# radio button selection before fired blur event of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code,

I have called blur event of textarea and on the basis of radio button's selected value it will update value of textarea. Problem is if I enter data in textarea first and then when I am going to choose radio button it will call blur event of textarea first and I am not able to change/select another/second radio button.

Is there any solution for this problem?
Thanks in advance.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td align="left">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" id="radioEditSingle" value="0" name="recurrenceEdit" checked /> RaditButton1
      </label>
      <label style="display:block">
        <input type="radio" id="radioEditAll" value="1" name="recurrenceEdit" /> RaditButton2
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <textarea id="txtEditRecReason" style="width:100%;resize:none" maxlength="500" class="form-control" onblur="txtEditRecReason_onBlur(this);" onkeypress="return PreventTextLengthOnType(this, 500, event);" onpaste="javascript:isAlertShown = false; return PreventTextLengthOnPaste(this, 500);"></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" id="hdnRecApptId" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is you requirement?

Comment: If I enter data in textarea first, then i want to change radiobutton. As radiobutton1 is by default checked, i wanted to change it to radiobutton2.

Comment: I think you have cornered yourself; onblur is triggered whenever focus moves away (similar to onfocusout); so you may want to rethink your approach

Comment: I have implemented another logic, I save data when clicked outside the table. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#txtEditRecReason").on("keyup",function() {
  if(this.value != "") {
    $("#radioEditAll").prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $("#radioEditSingle").prop("checked", true);
  }
});
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its **length** and **content**. Consider providing an explanation.